# Scrolling inside of a FullPage.js application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

I'm currently making a fullPage.js application.On a given page I want to have a picture with a boxed arrow pointing at the picture. Now I've managed to achieve this fine the problem is I need multiple of these box and picture elements on a page and as such I would like to be able to scroll through the elements on a given page.

Here is the JS, I clearly include the scrollOverflow property.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['Home', 'AboutMe', 'Education','Skills','Achievements','Portfolio','ContactMe'],
                slidesColor: ['purple', '#CA1E1E', '#F07A1A','#E7BC25', '#147727', '#1A77B4','#96A399'],
                'scrollOverflow': true, css3: true              
            });
        });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
                <h1  style="position:absolute;top:8%;left:45%;font-size:2em;" class="font2">consectetur</h1>

                <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:12.5%;width:65%">

                    <img  style="border-radius:50%;width:10%;border:5px solid #ffba00;position:absolute;left:0%;" src="images/plain.jpg">


                    <div class="arrow_box" style="left:15%;margin-top:-1%;padding:1.5%;border-radius:5px;color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat. cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>

                <div style="position:absolute;top:44%;left:12.5%;width:65%">
                    <img  style="border-radius:50%;border:5px solid #ffba00;width:10%;position:absolute;left:0%;font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;" src="images/plain.jpg">

                    <div class="arrow_box" style="left:15%;margin-top:-1%;padding:1.5%;border-radius:5px;color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat. cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>

                <div style="position:absolute;top:68%;left:12.5%;width:65%">
                    <img  style="border-radius:50%;width:10%;border:5px solid #ffba00;position:absolute;left:0%;font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;" src="images/plain.jpg">

                    <div class="arrow_box" style="left:15%;margin-top:-1%;padding:1.5%;border-radius:5px;color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat. cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>

                <div style="position:absolute;top:92%;left:12.5%;width:65%">
                    <img  style="border-radius:50%;width:10%;border:5px solid #ffba00;position:absolute;left:0%;font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;" src="images/plain.jpg">

                    <div class="arrow_box" style="left:15%;margin-top:-1%;padding:1.5%;border-radius:5px;color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans Light' !important;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco derit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat. cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the following:

[image]

The scrolling in is not kicking in and I'm not to sure why? Why ideas? Ideally the 4th box and image elements should appear in a scroll able manner

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is caused for using `position:absolute` in each of those elements. 
Try avoiding it, you shouldn't need it anyway.

Your code contain HTML mistakes, that could easily be the cause as well.
You can see them in red here: http://jsfiddle.net/gGL9V/